# Expanding string variables in bash to toggle a value in JSON

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a bash function where I can switch environments, below is what I tried. I installed the npm `json` package globally to edit the relevant file inline, but that may not be needed.

```
devUrl () { 'https://some-url.com'; }
testUrl () { 'https://some-test-url.com'; }
switchEnv () { 'json -I -f config.json -e "this.url = (this.url == "$1" ? "$2" : "$1")"'; }
alias switch='switchEnv devUrl testUrl';
```

what am I missing/doing wrong?

I also tried to template the strings `devUrl` and `testUrl` inside the double quotes in the `switchEnv` function, but that's where I got stuck.

Update:

I tried this:

```
devUrl='https://some-url.com'
testUrl='https://some-test-url.com'
switchEnv() { json -I -f config.json -e "this.url = (this.url == "$devUrl" ? "$testUrl" : "$devUrl")"; }
```

but got the following error:

```
this.url = (this.url == https://some-url.com ? https://some-test-url.com : https://some-url.com)
                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/json/lib/json.js:1289:27)
```

it doesn't like the `:` after https for some reason.

Comment: You can make life much easier on yourself you start small, e.g. with a function that just prints "hello world", and build out, rather than finishing your script and then trying to debug why it's not working.

Comment: You're mixing literal and syntactic quotes -- that doesn't work, because the shell treats the quotes around `"$devurl"` as *ending* the quoted string that started with `"this.url`, and then starting a new quoted string at the end of the expansion.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs for the `json` tool you're using?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy https://www.npmjs.com/package/json

Comment: ...so it doesn't support any means of passing data out-of-band from code? With my security hat on, my advice is not to use that tool.

Comment: noted, thank you... i'll start using jq moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is a sample implementation that does what you're looking for; see the notes below for some details on why it was implemented as it was.

```
# String assignments
devUrl='https://some-url.com'
testUrl='https://some-test-url.com'
configFile="$PWD/config.json"

# Functions
switchEnv() {
  local tempfile
  tempfile=$(mktemp "$configFile.XXXXXX")
  if jq --arg a "$1" \
        --arg b "$2" \
        'if .url == $a then .url=$b else .url=$a end' <"$configFile" >"$tempfile"; then
    mv -- "$tempfile" "$configFile"
  else
    rm -f -- "$tempfile"
    return 1
  fi
}
switch() { switchEnv "$devUrl" "$testUrl"; }
```

---

Notes:

- Unlike aliases, function bodies should be actual code, not strings containing code.
- Storing data (as opposed to code) should be done using variables (be they strings or arrays, as appropriate).
- Passing data out-of-band from code allows a malicious value of `devUrl` or `testUrl` to escape its quoting and run arbitrary `json` or `jq` commands. This is wise, in no small part because these languages become more powerful over time: Old versions of `jq` had no operations that wouldn't run in constant-time, whereas modern versions of the language allow code to be expressed that can be used for denial-of-service attacks; future versions might also add I/O support, allowing malicious code to have a wider array of surprising behaviors.

---

Now, let's say you were going to ignore the warning (above) about the importance of separating data and code. How would we modify your current code to behave "correctly" (when the strings being handled are non-malicious)?

```
switchEnv() {
  json -I -f config.json -e 'this.url = (this.url == "'"$devUrl"'" ? "'"$testUrl"'" : "'"$devUrl"'")'; }
}
```

Comment: updating my answer with what I tried based off of your answer, thx.